# wwwroot content prefixed by controller name

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

I have a Login page that isn't loading any CSS at all. It is because the page is looking for the following:

[image]

My wwwroot folder has the structure `css/login/login.css`, however the page is trying to prefix this with the name of the Controller (`AuthController`). The Page's header simply looks like so:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Webpage</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login/login.css">
</head>
```

My Controller is just in a folder named `Controllers` and my View is in a structure like so: `Views/Auth/`.

I am not using a `_Layout` page as of yet.

I haven't seen this before and I cannot workout why it is prefixing the Controller name to the content in `wwwroot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your style to

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/login/login.css">
```

Similar to how you can refer to relative paths (eg: `../css/login/login.css`) you can in Razor you can refer the virtual root path using the `~` operator.

Generally I find `~` more useful as you can change the location of your view and still refer to the same location.

Comment: I just tried this a few seconds before seeing this answer. It worked. Could you give a small explanation on why this works then I'm happy to accept it as an answer.